# Can't connect to any EC2 Linux instance

Tags: ssh, aws, key-authentication, putty, redmine

I'm facing a very simple issue here; I'm not able to connect to my Linux (bitnami-redmine-5.0.3-4-r06-linux-debian-11-x86_64) Virtual Machine.

I've created another sister VM to check, and can't connect from my PuTTY (Windows) and the error "No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)".

I've followed many tutorials step by step, and I can't connect.

To expand my information, when I try to connect via Windows Command Prompt and I do

```
C:\Users\leoca>ssh -i rescue-redminev2.pem admin@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for rescue-redminev2.pem are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "rescue-redminev2.pem": bad permissions
admin@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

and I edit the permissions and grant full access to my user, then this is shown:

```
C:\Users\leoca>ssh -i rescue-redminev2.pem admin@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
admin@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Use the private key you received while setting up the VM for ssh authentication.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: Thanks! didn't work

Comment: Modify the permission of the private key file.
https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open

Comment: Define "didn't work" with _much_ more precision.

Comment: I've changed the permission file, and the "Permission denied (publickey)." is shown

Comment: The type of problem seems related to Windows and not Unix/Linux, so maybe will be worth using the [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or the [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) website.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about configuring the Windows side, and should be asked over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

I login to AWS, launch an new instance, generate and download the new .ppk to connect, and when I want to use it in my new instance it tells me "No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)".

Comment: Instead of adding a new answer, it would be great if you could update the question with the new info. To do so, you need to click on the [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/722569/edit) button below it.